# How can i ensure that same values are not inserted into database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a table with PK = BookId and another non-key - BookName.
Can I ensure that the user does not add the same book again into the database, at the DB level. Or do i have to do it at the application level ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Unique Index`

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <idx_name> ON <table_name> (column1, column2)
```

Assuming your table is called Books, you could use

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_IdAndName_Unique ON [dbo].[Books] (BookId, BookName)
```

Comment: This won't prevent duplicate values for `BookName` unless the `BookID` happens to be the same (which is impossible since `BookID` is already a primary key).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add this as a constraint than a unique index, even though they are implemented the same behind the scenes. A constraint correctly implies the intent (to prevent duplicates), whereas an index implies to many that it was created for performance reasons.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Books ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_BookName
  UNIQUE (BookName);
```